Component disappear after changing position else statement
i have this component here:
enter image description here
and this is the code:
import React from "react";
import { BiLogoInstagramAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import { FaFacebookF } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export const LocationProfileCard = () => {
  const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser.reloadUserInfo.localId;

  if (user !== null) {
    get(child(dbRef, `locations/identify/${user}`))
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          let LocationName = snapshot.val().name;

          get(child(dbRef, `locations/public/${LocationName}/data/`)).then(
            (snapshot) => {},
          );
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    return (
      <div className="card_profile_location_wrapper">
        <div className="card_profile_form_location_wrapper">
          <form className="card_profile_form_location_main">
            <div className="card_profile_location_first_section">
              <div className="card_profile_location_logo">
                <label>Logo</label>
              </div>
              <div className="card_profile_location_social_media">
                <ul className="wrapper-socialmedia_card_profile">
                  <li className="icon-insta">
                    <span className="tooltip">Instagram</span>
                    <span>
                      <BiLogoInstagramAlt />
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li className="icon-face">
                    <span className="tooltip">Facebook</span>
                    <span>
                      <FaFacebookF />
                    </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card_profile_location_second_section">
              <div className="card_profile_location_data">
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <h3>Informationen</h3>
                <div className="card_profile_location_data_information_group">
                  <div className="card_profile_location_data_information">
                    <h3>Kapazität</h3>
                    <label>Daten</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card_profile_location_data_information">
                    <h3>Raucherbereich</h3>
                    <label>Daten</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card_profile_location_data_information">
                    <h3>Parkplätze</h3>
                    <label>Daten</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card_profile_location_data_information">
                    <h3>Verpfelgung</h3>
                    <label>Daten</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card_profile_location_data_information">
                    <h3>Barrierefreiheit</h3>
                    <label>Daten</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card_profile_location_third_section"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

As soon as i move this else statement at the bottom of the code (after the closing bracket of the  return block)
       } else {
   console.log("No data available");
 }

 
}).catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
});

the component disappears. I think the problem is, that i include the return block to my Javascript code. Is this the problem?
Could someone explain why?

Consistently formatting your code does indeed clearly reveal that if if (user !== null) is false then the component never returns anything.  Is that what you're referring to?  You can add another return to return a value in that case.  Note that making use of tools like TypeScript or a code linter can also help you spot issues like this, above and beyond simply being consistent with your use of indentation and other whitespace.

As an aside... Is this meant to be a server-side component or something?  Because invoking a data-fetching operation directly in the rendering of the component is very unusual and probably not what you're looking to do.  Though it's not really clear what you are looking to do in this case since nothing seems to use the result of that operation.

@David thank you so much for you help and the hint with TypeScript and linter. I will take a look on this.
I would like to get Data from Firebase Database and show it into the component.
